How to get my payment from international client?
I am a freelancer. I was contacted from a client on FB Hannah Taylor from Germany company Deutsche telecommunications. She said me to contact her on telegram.
She offered me 2000$ for doing 36 pages PDF to convert into MS word form by typing, in two days.
I did it in one day. And submit the project on companies email address. Which was accepted after reviewing and ask me to contact the payment manager. He asked me my information and photo. Photo was not included in initial corespondents before giving me project and Hannah said when you submit work you get paid immediately nothing else.
When I refuse to give my photo they said this is company policy without my photo they can not send me payment. I have done international payments before only bank account details are needed.
I ask several times to Hannah before submitting my project to send me details of payment method from Germany but they didn't have clear answer just to finish project.
I want to file a petition against them and sue them for fraudulent correspondence and changing statement.
Can you guide me In this petition case.

The cost of suing someone can be multiple times the value of what they didn't pay you.

This seems pretty suspicious.  Deutch Telecom has a huge number of administrative staff who can convert a PDF file to Word, retyping the document rather than using a tool is useless busywork, large companies have processes to vet new freelancers that would take far longer than it would take to convert the document, $2000 is a ridiculous amount to pay for such a thing, and communicating on Telegram is very weird.  I would wager this is a scam to try to get details from you and the request to retype the document is just to ensure you've invested enough time that you'd be willing to divulge info

According to me this is some kind of scam friend. First they offer $$$$ for the job which can be done freely or in house (if they are big firm) or for the less amount $$. Second thing is big companies or professionals use emails for this kind of communication. You can do further process only if someone send email from their official mail or someone contacted through companies linkedin account otherwise I don't think so there is any other way.

That is clearly a scam. Business transactions should be done through legitimate email and not just through facebook chat.
